# Using a boost::numeric::ublas::vector directly as function argument without initialization

Tags: c++, vector, boost

I am trying something which I would think is relatively simple but am at a loss how to do it. I have a function which as an argument takes a boost::numeric::ublas::vector, instead of having to declare the vector beforehand I want to be able to just declare it inside the function as rvalue, is this possible with boost::numeric::ublas::vector?

Now I do it like this

```
 boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> point(3);
 point <<= 1, 2, 3;
 test(point);
```

I would like to do it something like this, which is possible for normal std::vectors with list initialization.

```
 test( {1,2,3} )
```

Is this possible or can't you do it with boost::numeric::ublas::vector this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [the uBLAS FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html#6FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> uBLAS is more than 10 years old and missed all new stuff from C++11.

So it seems unlikely that list initialization will be added.

If you need to use uBLAS and want list-initialization, I suggest implementing a helper function for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not specifically want list initialization, I just want to be able to call a function with a boost vector as inline created rvalue in the function argument.

Comment: Or are you saying that this can only be done via list-initialization, and so in principle cannot be done in older version of C++?

Comment: I'd suggest writing a small helper function for that. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459318/how-to-create-a-nonempty-boost-ublasvector-inside-an-initializer-list) is an example how one can do it.